# NER prections with distilbert transformer model

Tags: bert, transformer, text-classification, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract 'agreement date' label from a corpus of legal contracts. In the train dataset, I used pytorch-transformer model to train.

```
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, num_labels=len(label_list))
```

Here label_list is the IOB format which gives ['B-Date', 'I-Date', 'O'] and model_checkpoint is "distilbert-base-uncased"
I train the dataset after defining TrainingArguements, datacollator and matrics computaitons from predictions

```
model_output_dir = 'C:/Python/model_output_dir'

args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = model_output_dir,
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
    logging_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    num_train_epochs=3,    
    run_name = model_checkpoint,
    metric_for_best_model="f1",
    load_best_model_at_end = True,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    )

from transformers import DataCollatorForTokenClassification
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer)
from seqeval.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, classification_report

def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

    # Remove ignored index (special tokens)
    true_predictions = [
        [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)]
    true_labels = [
        [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)]

    # Define the metric parameters
    overall_precision = precision_score(true_labels, true_predictions, zero_division=1)
    overall_recall = recall_score(true_labels, true_predictions, zero_division=1)
    overall_f1 = f1_score(true_labels, true_predictions, zero_division=1)
    overall_accuracy = accuracy_score(true_labels, true_predictions)
    
    # Return a dictionary with the calculated metrics
    return {
        "precision": overall_precision,
        "recall": overall_recall,
        "f1": overall_f1,
        "accuracy": overall_accuracy,}

trainer = Trainer(
                model= model,
                args = args,
                train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
                eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["test"],
                data_collator=data_collator,
                tokenizer=tokenizer,
                compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
                )
```

My input training data after preprocessing look like this
[image]

My test data has agreement text only in tokenized form. When I predict I get the big tensor like below
[image]

How I get the required date label from this output ?

Comment: You are trying to extract a custom label "Agreement Date", right? If yes, shouldn't you train your model to recognize "Agreement Dates" with a custom dataset  in the first place?

Comment: Yes, of course. The training is done with a dataset having 'agreement date' label for each of the given contracts

Comment: Sorry, I'm not shur if I've well understood, but here is an answer anyway. The output is actually a set of probabilities. It is a raw result and you should take the highest score with argmax that would define the most probable solution. For instance, [0.2 , 0.6 , 0.3] would have the 2nd result as solution ('I-Date').